# python TCP server doesn't recognize string

Tags: python

I'm writing a client for my raspberry pi in python. When it takes the letter 'm' it should return songs in the folder. But it doesn't recognize the message. Here is the code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os
BUFSIZE=1024

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address=('localhost',1234)

print >>sys.stderr,'connecting to %s port %s' %server_address

sock.connect(server_address)

message_to_put='Connected to %s port %s' %server_address

response=sock.recv(BUFSIZE)
#response='m'
if response=='m':
    print 'inside if'
    songs=os.listdir("music/")
    songs.sort()
    sock.sendall(bytes(songs))

print response
```

I try the code in my linux before RPi but it doesn't enter to the if clause even though when I print the response, it prints as 'm'.

I'm using Java Server which I have written, that sends the message as PrintStream.println(). But I don't think the server is the problem because I tried it in java clients and it worked fine. I think there is a problem at changing bytes to string in python. 
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: You may have to decode it first before you can successfully compare it with a normal string. Are you sure it doesn't print something like b'm' ?

Comment: I suspect your response has a newline attached. You might try `if response[0] == 'm'` or you could try using `response.strip()` before the comparison.

Comment: `response.strip()` solved the case. Thank you